# Swift bad connection detect

Tags: swift, error-handling, connection, reachability

I have a Swift app that parse an url. All is ok, i use reachability to show an alert view when connection is off. The problem is when connection is on but it's very bad or lost. When i start my app it crashes because unable to load the url. There is a simple method to avoid this? an alert that knows when your connection is very bad and prevent app crashing? 
the code is this:

```
public class Reachability {
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }
    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}}
```

No crash log (occurs only on iphone when i set network link conditioner on 100% loss profile). I need a connection handle error that knows when user internet connection become bad. Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: it will help if you post your code or at least the crash log

Comment: Solved with 24334675 by Najmul Hasan! thanks